# How to get an object array's field?

Tags: php, arrays

I currently receive an array with this structure:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile Object
        (
            [test:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 
            [originalName:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => apple-tv-ad
.jpg
            [mimeType:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => image/jpeg
            [size:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 36555
            [error:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 0
            [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => /private/var/tmp/phpe6INuk
            [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => phpe6INuk
        )

)
```

When I try to `print_r($file[0]['originalName']);` I receive a 500 internal server error. I try to upload a file via an AJAX call. Once my mediaUpload method is called, I want to make the database entry with the appropriate values received through this array. I am just stuck at how to access it. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `$file[0]->originalName;` as it's a Object, not an array that you acces through `$file[0]`. But it's private, so you can't acces it.

Comment: Same error :(. Is there no way to get the value if it's private?

Comment: No, not possible. Look at the documentation about visibility [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php). Unless there is a function that accesses this value through the class, as you can see in the documentation as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`getClientOriginalName()`](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html#method_getClientOriginalName) method. (Sorry for the short answer, but that's pretty much all there is to it.)

```
$name = $file[0]->getClientOriginalName();
```

The UploadedFile object has different accessor methods you can use to get all the different pieces of information you need. They're all there in the API docs I linked.